# Добавить параметры в адрес ссылки chilkat

Tags: c#

Собственно, отправляю пост запрос по ссылке https://mysite.com/login?preferredLanguageCode=EN но ссылка обрезается и получается запрос идет на https://mysite.com/login без параметров:

```
req.AddParam("username", Login);
req.AddParam("password", Password);
string post = http.PostUrlEncoded("https://mysite.com/login?preferredLanguageCode=EN", req).BodyStr;
```

Comment: Вероятно, ваш сервис ожидает GET-запрос, а вы используете POST?